How to return lowest result from sequence column
I'm new to learning oracle sql, so I'm sure this has a simple solution that I'm missing, but I'm trying to return the first sequence row from each order, not just limit the whole query results to 1 returned row.  The query I'm working with is this:
select som.bi_wo_workord
, som.BI_SO_NBR
, wft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr
, wf.bi_dist_ofc_cd
, wft.bi_work_event_cd
from bi_so_master som
join bi_so_det sod on sod.bi_so_nbr = som.bi_so_nbr    
join bi_wrkflw_tasks wft on wft.bi_wrkflw_key = sod.bi_wrkflw_key
join bi_wrkflw wf on wf.bi_wrkflw_key = sod.bi_wrkflw_key
where som.bi_open_dt > '01-JAN-24'
and wft.bi_work_event_cd in ('QUEUE','START')
order by som.bi_so_nbr, wft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr

which returns data like this:
"BI_WO_WORKORD","BI_SO_NBR","BI_WRKFLW_TASK_SEQ_NBR","BI_DIST_OFC_CD","BI_WORK_EVENT_CD"
"21003821","21003821",39,"HDH","QUEUE"
"21003821","21003821",39.5,"HDH","QUEUE"
"21003821","21003821",40,"HDH","QUEUE"
"21003821","21003821",41,"HDH","QUEUE"
"21003821","21003821",42,"HDH","QUEUE"
"22007385","22007385",7,"LMC","QUEUE"
"22007385","22007385",10,"LMC","QUEUE"
"22007385","22007385",11,"LMC","QUEUE"
"23002645","23002645",14,"KEP","QUEUE"
"23002645","23002645",15,"KEP","QUEUE"
"23002645","23002645",16,"KEP","QUEUE"
"23002645","23002645",17,"KEP","QUEUE"

What I'm trying to return is the first (lowest number) of each sequence number (wft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr) from each service order (som.BI_SO_NBR).
Like so:
"BI_WO_WORKORD","BI_SO_NBR","BI_WRKFLW_TASK_SEQ_NBR","BI_DIST_OFC_CD","BI_WORK_EVENT_CD"
"21003821","21003821",39,"HDH","QUEUE"
"22007385","22007385",7,"LMC","QUEUE"
"23002645","23002645",14,"KEP","QUEUE"

I've done some searching and tried:
select * from (
select som.bi_wo_workord
, som.BI_SO_NBR
, wft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr
, wf.bi_dist_ofc_cd
, wft.bi_work_event_cd
, sod.bi_map_loc_nbr
, row_number() over (partition by som.bi_so_nbr order by sft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr) as row_num 
from bi_so_master som
join bi_so_det sod on sod.bi_so_nbr = som.bi_so_nbr    
join bi_wrkflw_tasks wft on wft.bi_wrkflw_key = sod.bi_wrkflw_key
join bi_wrkflw wf on wf.bi_wrkflw_key = sod.bi_wrkflw_key
where som.bi_open_dt > '01-JAN-24'
and wft.bi_work_event_cd in ('QUEUE','START')
) as grouped_task_seq
where row_num = 1;

but this, of course, throws an error ("SQL command not properly ended") and it feels like maybe I'm going down the wrong path and making it overly complicated.

You are actually really close and got the the analytic function part correct. The problem is that the "AS" keyword in Oracle only works for column aliases, not table aliases. Just remove that keyword and your query should work. (And I also recommend you use the date literal `date '2024-01-01' instead of the implicit date format of a string.)

Thank you, I must be nearly there!  But when I remove "as grouped_task_seq" it throws "ORA-00904: "SFT"."BI_WRKFLW_TASK_SEQ_NBR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 8 Column: 58"  which seems like its pointing at the OVER clause?

I just noticed I had the wrong prefix on the sequence number name in the over clause, changed "sft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr" to "wft.bi_wrkflw_task_seq_nbr" and it ran without an error.  thank you Jon
